# What is a good translation of "Rüstzeit" or "Retooling time"?

Tags: traduction, anglais, allemand

I'm looking for a concise translation for "**Rüstzeit**" or "**Retooling time**". This is the time taken to reconfigure a machine for a new batch of work. (Installing new tools, new NC program etc.)

Does "**temps de réoutillage**" sound right?

Comment: See also [What is a good translation of “Rüstzeit”?](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2541/what-is-a-good-translation-of-rustzeit) (into English) on [german.se].

Answer (score 6):

Some [dictionary](http://www.mijnwoordenboek.nl/vertaal/DE/FR/R%C3%BCstzeit) gives "période de préparation et de nettoyage
", "temps d'équipement", "temps de préparation" and "temps d'apprêt".

I think your own proposition is much clearer, but "réoutillage" isn't in the dictionary (although as Gilles comments, it doesn't mean it's not a valid word). So I would propose "temps de [changement d'outil](http://www.max-computer.de/x5f/hf-osada_.html)" as an alternative.

Comment: *Réoutillage* is a word, both because *outillage* is a word and `re-` is a productive prefix (prescriptive approach) and because [people use it](http://www.google.com/search?q=r%C3%A9outillage) (descriptive approach). However I have [reservations](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/1234) as to its suitability for this particular meaning.

Answer (score 6):

The [IATE](http://iate.europa.eu/iatediff/SearchByQuery.do) database (European Union terminology database) has entries for *Rüstzeit*:

- *temps de démontage* (*dismantling time*) for *Abrüstzeit* in labor law (« temps nécessaire au démontage d'une machine une fois la production terminée »);
- *temps d'apprêt* ou *temps de préparation* ou *temps d'équipement* (*set up time*) for *Aufrüstzeit* in labor law;
- *période de préparation et de nettoyage* in agriculture;
- *temps mort* (*idle time*) in technology (« partie du temps utilisable pendant lequel on ne fait pas travailler l'unité fonctionnelle »).

IATE does not have an entry for *retooling* (in this sense). The word *réoutillage* is not present in standard dictionaries (it is neither in the [*Trésor de la langue française*](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tr%C3%A9sor_de_la_langue_fran%C3%A7aise) nor in the [*Petit Robert*](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petit_Robert)). Nonetheless, the word *[outillage](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/outillage)* is standard, and the prefix `re-` is very productive, so using the word *réoutillage* is not a problem in itself. What is more problematic is that most of the [uses I find online](http://www.google.com/search?q=r%C3%A9outillage) are about retooling a factory in the sense of buying and installing new equipment, not in the sense of adapting the existing tools for a new product. This seems to be the case [in English](http://www.google.com/search?q=retooling) as well, though. Most of the examples in the [Linguee](http://www.linguee.com/english-french/translation/retooling.html) dictionary have *retooling* translated by *réoutillage*. Linguee doesn't have a German to French translation, but the [German to English translation list](http://www.linguee.com/english-german/search?query=R%FCstzeit) suggests *(re)tooling time* (hence *temps d'outillage* or *temps de réoutillage*, though I don't find this meaning of the word *outillage* in my dictionaries) or *setup time* (hence *temps de préparation*).

Comment: Bonne et intéressante reponte (du verbe repondre, bien entendu)

Answer (score 5):

I think the term would be

> Temps de changement de série

or

> Temps de changement de production

As you program you tool chain to produce a serie.

It is the terms employed on the wikipedia [page](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%E9thode_SMED) of the SMED method in French.

Comment: Seeing your link, I would also suggest "temps de réglage"